# Netlogo let turtles random walk within an area

Tags: netlogo

Suppose I have a beach and an ocean, denoted by patch colors gray and cyan respectively. I have some turtles (fish) whose starting location I constrained randomly somewhere in the ocean. Now each tick the fish move following a random walk with step length drawn from a normal distribution (mean=0, SD=1). Logically, when moving the fish should stay within the ocean and not move onto the beach. I tried the same `while []` that i used to constrain the starting locations of fish to the ocean, but this doesn't seem to work here i.e. the fish don't move at all. Any thoughts?

EDIT: In addition to having 2 fishes in the water, i have 2 other turtles (e.g., cow and sheep) on land that, similarly to the fishes, cannot/shouldn't enter the water when they move (in fact I have 3 such 'habitats' total where turtles shouldn't leave the habitats in which they started). When I incorporate the solution by LeirsW for the fish and for the cows/sheep, my Netlogo freezes and i have to force quit. Any thoughts on this?

EDIT 2: the x0 and y0 are no mistakes and need to be kept in the code.

Updated code below:

```
breed [ fishes fish ]

fishes-own
[
  x0 y0 xcur ycur
]

to setup

  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  ask patches [set pcolor gray]
  ask patches with [ pycor < (max-pycor / 2) ] [ set pcolor cyan ]

  create-fishes 4
    [
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      set x0 xcor
      set y0 ycor

      ifelse who <= ( 3 * 0.5 )      
        [ set shape "fish" set size 2 ]
        [ set shape "fish" set size 3 ]

      set color white

      while [ pcolor != cyan ] [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]                  
    ]

  create-fishes 4
    [
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor
      set x0 xcor
      set y0 ycor

      ifelse who <= ( 4 - 1 + 4 * 0.5 )
        [ set shape "sheep" set size 2 set color yellow ]
        [ set shape "cow" set size 2  set color yellow]

      ;set color white

      while [ pcolor != gray ] [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]                          ]

end

to go

  fish-move

  tick

end

to fish-move

  ask fishes with [pcolor = cyan]
    [

          ifelse (random-float 1) < 0.95
            [
              let destination patch (x0 + random-normal 0 1) (y0 + random-normal 0 1)

              while [ [pcolor] of destination != cyan ]
                [
                  set destination patch (x0 + random-normal 0 1) (y0 + random-normal 0 1)
                ]
              move-to destination

              set xcur xcor
              set ycur ycor
            ]
            [
              let destination patch random-xcor random-ycor

              while [ [pcolor] of destination != cyan ]
                [
                  set destination patch random-xcor random-ycor
                ]
              move-to destination

              set xcur xcor
              set ycur ycor
            ]

          ]

  ask fishes with [pcolor = gray]
    [


          ifelse (random-float 1) < 0.95
            [
              let destination patch (x0 + random-normal 0 1) (y0 + random-normal 0 1)

              while [ [pcolor] of destination != gray ]
                [
                  set destination patch (x0 + random-normal 0 1) (y0 + random-normal 0 1)
                ]
              move-to destination

              set xcur xcor
              set ycur ycor
            ]
            [
              let destination patch random-xcor random-ycor

              while [ [pcolor] of destination != gray ]
                [
                  set destination patch random-xcor random-ycor
                ]
              move-to destination

              set xcur xcor
              set ycur ycor
            ]
        ]


end
```

Comment: Note that, in the `create-fishes` command block, using `move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = cyan]` is a more efficient way to bring fish to the sea, compared to the `while` loop where each fish might have to change location multiple times before finding a legal spot

Comment: Great, makes perfect sense. thank you! Still trying to understand the language.

Comment: @FlyingDutch is there a specific reason for you using a single breed here? It would make more sense to either use no breed at all (with them just being turtles) or to use a different breed for your different habitats.

Comment: I believe I answered this question in on of my my comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: As the question has been changed, I feel it warrants a new answer rather than editing the previous answer which is in and off itself still correct. However, as I have only joined stackoverflow relatively recently, I will follow someone elses judgement and append this to my previous post if requested.

In your new version, the `x0` and `y0` are creating your problems. You define them before shuffeling your turtles around to find a good initial position. This means that a fish can have its `x0` and `y0` set to the land. Since your code has them looking for a destination around that point, rejecting all gray destinations, you will be stuck in an endless searching. Moving `x0` and `y0` to the end of the `create-fishes` block solves this problem.

```
 create-fishes 4
  [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    
    ifelse who <= ( 3 * 0.5 )       ; Set proportion of fishes in lagoon determined by slider
      [ set shape "fish" set size 2 ]
    [ set shape "fish" set size 3 ]
    
    set color white
    
    while [ pcolor != cyan ] [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]   
    
    set x0 xcor
    set y0 ycor
 ]
```

Now for some further general suggestions

- I added a fishes-own variable called habitat. This variable is set to a color at creating of the fishes and determines which color of patches they can move to. By making this a variable tied to the turtles, you don't need a new movement code for each new type of turtle.
- I added Matteo's suggestion of more efficiently choosing their initial patch by having them `move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = [habitat] of myself]`.
- I grouped all the initial moving together in a separate code block, just to not have to rewrite it for every different type of turtle you want to add.
- Do `xcur` and `ycur` have any specific goal? You can already access `xcor` and `ycor` on all turtles so I don't see any specific need for them.
- Is there any specific goal for the fishes breed? Otherwise you could just use the general agentset `turtles` instead and define `turtles-own` instead of `fishes-own`. Even if you have multiple breeds, any variable defined as `turtles-own` can also be used by your breeds so you won't have to define them for each breed separately.

  ```
   breed [ fishes fish ]

   fishes-own
   [
     x0 y0 xcur ycur habitat
   ]

   to setup

     clear-all
     reset-ticks

     ask patches [set pcolor gray]
     ask patches with [ pycor < (max-pycor / 2) ] [ set pcolor cyan ]

     create-fishes 4 ;create the water animals
     [
       ifelse who <= ( 3 * 0.5 )       
         [ set shape "fish" set size 2 ]
       [ set shape "fish" set size 3 ]

       set color white
       set habitat cyan
     ]

     create-fishes 4 ;create the land animals
     [
       ifelse who <= ( 4 - 1 + 4 * 0.5 )
         [ set shape "sheep" set size 2 ]
       [ set shape "cow" set size 2 ]

       set color yellow
       set habitat gray
     ]

     ask fishes [   ;move all animals to their prefered habitat
       move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = [habitat] of myself]

       set x0 xcor
       set y0 ycor
     ]

   end

   to go

     fish-move

     tick

   end

   to fish-move

     ask fishes
       [

         ifelse (random-float 1) < 0.95
           [
             let destination patch (x0 + random-normal 0 1) (y0 + random-normal 0 1)

             while [ [pcolor] of destination != habitat ]
               [
                 set destination patch (x0 + random-normal 0 1) (y0 + random-normal 0 1)
             ]
             move-to destination

             set xcur xcor
             set ycur ycor
         ]
         [
           let destination patch random-xcor random-ycor

           while [ [pcolor] of destination != habitat ]
             [
               set destination patch random-xcor random-ycor
           ]
           move-to destination

           set xcur xcor
           set ycur ycor
         ]

     ]

   end
  ```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for. Your explanation & rationale makes coding look so simple. I see clearly now how the order of commands, which i clearly didn't think through, caused the issues. I will think more carefully in the future. I also like the way how you condensed the code to make it look more elegant than just copy pastes. I am adapting NetLogo code that i received from someone else; still figuring out the purpose of xcur/ycur. I am not using general 'turtles' agentset as my main turtles are actually sharks. With their prey fish. 'turtles' would just add confusion imo.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with your code is that you ask your fishes to only move while they are on a non-cyan tile. Since they all start on a cyan tile, non of them will move.

A first way to go about this would be to simply ask them to move once, and then move again as long as they are on the grey

```
to fish-move

  ask fishes
    [
      setxy (x0 + random-normal 0 1 ) (y0 + random-normal 0 1 )
      while [ pcolor != cyan ]
        [
          setxy (x0 + random-normal 0 1 ) (y0 + random-normal 0 1 )
        ]
    ] 
  
end
```

Now this brings with it its own set of problems, because it means that fishes that come near the grey may move onto it and travel a long distance before finally ending in a cyan tile again. That is why I prefer to split the problem into three parts: Choosing the destination, evaluating the destination, moving to the destination.
For this, you can use `let` to create a local variable that is creatively named "destination":

`let destination patch (xcor + random-normal 0 1 ) (ycor + random-normal 0 1 )`

Then we continue by evaluating whether or not destination is a viable patch and, if necessary, choosing a new destination:

`while [ [pcolor] of destination != cyan ] [ set destination <...> ]`

And then finally, after a satisfying destination has been found, moving to it:

`move-to destination`

Now I did also notice that you give each fish a `x0` and `y0` and you never update them. Are the fish meant to continuously hover around the same patch? I assumed not so I removed them and let the fishes determine their destination based on their current location instead (`xcor` and `ycor`)

```
breed [ fishes fish ]

to setup

  clear-all
  reset-ticks

  ask patches [set pcolor gray]                                           
  ask patches with [ pycor < (max-pycor / 2) ] [ set pcolor cyan ]        
 
  create-fishes 4
    [
      setxy random-xcor random-ycor

      set shape "fish" set size 2.5 set color white 

      while [ pcolor != cyan ] [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]                   
    ]

end

to go
  
  fish-move
  
  tick
 
end

to fish-move
  
  ask fishes
    [let destination patch (xcor + random-normal 0 1 ) (ycor + random-normal 0 1 )
  
     while [ [pcolor] of destination != cyan ]
       [
         set destination patch (xcor + random-normal 0 1 ) (ycor + random-normal 0 1 )
       ]
     move-to destination
    ] 

 end
```

As a last note, you could also use

`let destination patch-at (random-normal 0 1) (random-normal 0 1)`

which is a slightly shorter way of writing it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Your explanation as to why my fish won't move in the ocean makes sense. I just don't know how to reconcile that with the same code that i used to setup the fishes in the cyan habitat that does seem to work.

Comment: @FlyingDutch What aspects do you need to reconcile? The code that LeirsW gave you should work regardless of how fish are placed in the cyan habitat

Comment: Let me try to explain my lack of understanding in different way: in the setup block, the "while [ pcolor != cyan ] ..." puts turtles in the cyan habitat. However, when i copy paste the same code in the fish-move block, it is interpreted as to only move in a non-cyan tyle?

Comment: @FlyingDutch I think you are confusing it here. Your while code did exactly the same in the setup as in the go procedure, namely moving when the fishes are in the grey and stopping the movement as soon as the fishes are in the cyan. If you manually put a fish in the grey habitat and then press go, it would immediately move to cyan and then stop moving with your original code.

Comment: @LeirsW Despite the workable solution for my original question i.e. how to confine movements of turtles within one 'habitat' block, i have multiple blocks where turtles aren't allowed to move outside the habitat in which they started. I edited my OP to include a second habitat block where turtles move but cannot leave. How would the code look like?

Comment: @FlyingDutch Hmm, I would probably create a turtles-own variable with a certain color as name, and only allow turtles to move if their destination has that color. I will look into it during a break

Comment: @LeirsW I'm still confused regarding the interpretation of the 'while [...] command. According to the NetLogo dictionary, 'if reporter in while reports false, exit the loop. Otherwise run commands and repeat'. So for 'while [ pcolor != cyan ] [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]', my interpretation is that the reporter reports false when pcolor = cyan, therefore exit the loop. This is clearly the exact opposite of what happens when I run the code. What don't i understand?

Comment: @FlyingDutch Your interpretation is correct, that is exactly what happens. The important thing here is that you first do `setxy random-xcor random-ycor` and then  `while [ pcolor != cyan ] [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]`. You first give them a random location and then start checking the loop. If the location is already cyan, there is no reason to loop since they are already on a valid spot. If the location is not cyan, you loop until their location is cyan, which is a valid spot and thus means you should exit the loop.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation, i understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

In NetLogo, patches are identified with integer coordinates. That is, `patch 0.4 0.4` is the same as `patch 0 0`. NetLogo rounds the given coordinates to the nearest integer when locating patches. So, if your code involves adding a random value between 0 and 1 to each of the coordinates of a patch, chances are that the newly calculated coordinates refer to the same old patch. This may justify why turtles given a newly calculated destination seem to remain in their old place.

An alternative approach to your problem is to ask turtles to move forward by a distance. Here is an example in which I tell turtles to check where it is headed, and to change course if necessary:

```
ask turtles with [pcolor = cyan] [
  let dist random-normal 0 1 
  while ([pcolor] of patch-at-heading-and-distance heading dist) != cyan [
    set heading random-float 360
  ]
  fd dist
]
```

In the above code, variable `dist` is defined as the distance of movement (with negative values causing backward movement), `heading` is the property of turtles which indicates their orientation, and `fd` is the NetLogo function that tells turtles to move forward in the direction of their heading.

As a side note, `random-normal` and `random-float` are two different functions. Specifically, note that `random-normal 0 1` draws random numbers from a normal distribution with mean 0 and standard deviation 1, whereas `random-float 1` gives a random number between 0 and 1.

Comment: Good point! I will have to think whether it would be better to increase the SD a little bit, which should to more extent solve the issue of 'not' moving. However, the random walk process reflects the biology of the species i'm trying to model in a general sense. So your alternative solution, while perhaps good in other other contexts, would not be appropriate here.

Comment: @FlyingDutch Indeed the suggested approach is also a random walk, only defined in polar coordinates. However, since the main issue of this problem was immobility of turtles, I only focused on that part, assuming that variable 'dist' is defined properly. To address your interest in the full implementation of random walk, I edited the answer and added a line to the code with definition of movement distance (variable 'dist'). Note that distance is taken from a normal distribution whereas heading is taken from a uniform distribution.

Comment: Ah i see, then this answer would qualify as well. thanks for an alternative view :)